# GlimmerHMM giving “segmentation fault” error during gene prediction

Tags: segmentation-fault

I am trying to do gene prediction using GlimmerHMM. Training model was successfully completed but during prediction its giving "segmentation fault".

```
command : glimmerhmm_linux_x86_64 input.fasta -d Directory -o glimmer_results.gff -g
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this particular program, but perhaps this post will help you...

I assume you are referring to this program [glimmerhmm download page](ftp://ftp.cbcb.umd.edu/pub/software/glimmerhmm).

If so... did you compile the program from source or did you manage to get a pre-compiled 64 bit version?

When I run the compiled program, without any options, on my machine I get the options menu like this:

```
USAGE:  ./glimmerhmm <genome1-file> <training-dir-for-genome1> [options] 
Options:
-p file_name     If protein domain searches are available, read them from file file_name
-d dir_name      Training directory is specified by dir_name (introduced for compatibility with earlier versions)
-o file_name     Print output in file_name; if n>1 for top best predictions, output is in file_name.1, file_name.2, ... , file_name.n f
-n n             Print top n best predictions
-g               Print output in gff format
-v               Don't use svm splice site predictions
-f               Don't make partial gene predictions
-h               Display the options of the program
```

The program's usage menu indicates seems to match your command line option list.

So there are a few possibilities:

1. Somehow the build of the program went awry and doesn't function... missing library or something.
2. There is no directory named `Directory` and instead you will need to specify something like `~/my_training_directory`
3. You are attempting to run a 64 bit program on a 32 bit machine.